# Why is a max-width / height img not constrained by the parent percentage height / width in Firefox?

Tags: css, image, firefox, position, vertical-alignment

I have a set of absolutely positioned fluid divs within a container and want to display an image within each div that is vertically and horizontally centred within the container and fills up as much of the available space as possible. Due to using these images for other purposes they have to be img tags and not background images (otherwise with CSS3 this would be easy!)

I would have thought the following code should do just this but for some reason on Firefox the image displays in it's original dimensions and is not constrained by the parent dimensions. In Chrome the width seems to be correctly linked to the container however the img height is not constrained by the container height.

I could understand it if there was no width/height set on the parent but every element in this example has a percentage width/height set so i don't think this is the problem. FYI if you set a specific width:100% on the img then this constrains the width correctly (but can't be done as it means it's loses the correct aspect) however it still doesn't work for height even if you set the height to 100%,

You can see a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/xrzk084d/ and the code is below.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to what i'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated!

```
    body, html, #outer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #container {
        background-color: #ffcc00;
        display: table;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        top: 30%;
        width: 60%;
        height: 40%;
    }

    #containerinner {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #containerinner img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }

    <div id="outer">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="containerinner">
                <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wypn5e7n5bgeoic/landscape.png?dl=0" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: You can't have display table-cell immediately after display table AFAIK

Comment: The same happens if you include a display:table-row inbetween: http://jsfiddle.net/xrzk084d/2/

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that set a vertical alignment of middle is impossible without specifying the height of the containing element. In your situation, you want the height to be relative to the viewport which creates additional difficulty.

However, if we use both the `vh` (viewport height) and `vw` (viewport width) units defined in CSS3 we can achieve what you're after. I have then assumed that you want your image to be center aligned and with a max width and height of 60% and 40% of the viewport respective. I have reduced the markup to the following (**[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrzk084d/6/)**):

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 20vw;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

#inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 60vw;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 60vw;
  max-height: 40vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wypn5e7n5bgeoic/landscape.png?dl=0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“it's invalid CSS to have a display: table-cell whose immediate parent doesn't have a display: table-row”_ – says who? (Besides you, I mean.) It’s setting `table-layout: fixed` that does the trick here, the additional element is not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much, this solves the vertical alignment and width issues however the img still does not fit to the height of the container? The container should always be 40% height of the body/parent but if you make the viewport very short then you can see the image forces it to be taller than this (even though the img should be max 100% of the parent height which is 40% of the body?)

Comment: @CBroe you're right - although it would be invalid HTML to omit it,  an anonymous element with table-row styling will be drawn if it's ommited. *"For each 'table-cell' box C in a sequence of consecutive internal table and 'table-caption' siblings, if C's parent is not a 'table-row' then generate an anonymous 'table-row' box around C and all consecutive siblings of C that are 'table-cell' boxes."* (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes)

Comment: @deshg I haven't found this issue, what browser & version are you using?

Comment: I'm getting this same problem on FF, Chrome and IE. In the fiddle if you make the body area less tall then the height of the parent and img don't seem to resize to the 40% height of the parent? I've tried on real browsers (not just jsfiddle) and it's the same. It seems to be honouring the width settings but not the height for some reason (if i delete the image then when you make the body less tall then it resizes the container correctly)

Comment: Thanks so much you're a legend, i've banging my head against this one for ages and can't quite understand what is going wrong!

Comment: @deshg is that what you're after?

Comment: Functionality wise that's EXACTLY what i'm looking for :) However very sadly I cannot use vh/vw units for this due to the vh/vw issues within iOS: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units (I tried using vh previously but due to the iOS bugs it wasn't viable :( ). So do you think this means it's impossible to do within a fluid container without JS (which is not good given it's all fluid and can change shape/size in lots of cases)?